# Pycharm (flask) static files are not loading changes to HTML unless I try to reuse port 5000

Tags: ubuntu, flask, pycharm

Ok, so basically, I see changes made to static HTML files in Pycharm if I open up Spyder and get the "address already in use" message.

If I make changes to static html files in pycharm, I am not able to debug, nor am I able to see the changes in the browser on port 5000, no matter what. I tried invalidating caches. I tried exiting pycharm. I rebooted Ubuntu. But the page served by localhost:5000 still has the old content in it... UNTIL:

I open up Spyder and point it to the codebase that Pycharm is using. I get a message saying the address is already in use (it is).

At this point, and only at this point, if I refresh my Chrome browser (localhost:5000), it hits my breakpoints AND loads my changes (I can see changes that I made in the HTML).

Can anyone explain to me what is happening? Or theorize?

Comment: How do you run your flask app? Is it in debug mode?

Comment: I'm running it in pycharm in debug mode, but not in flask: app.run(), not app.run(debug=True)

Comment: The underlying werkzeug library has debugger middleware. When you run the app through pycharm you are not using that.

Comment: I'm showing it to a buddy to make sure I'm not insane; it appears once you hit port 5000 with spyder 2.0 you can even exit spyder at that point and pycharm will hit the breakpoints and show changed HTML content as it should. I have no theories.

Comment: If I do python newFlask.py (my project main python file), outside of all IDE's, it updates correctly. Outside of spyder, outside of pycharm...